# Why am I passing {'things[]' : [ 'apple', 'pillow']} form data?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, mongoose

I have very simple schema in node.js / mongoose that looks like this:

```
var thingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    thing_name  :  String,
    ting_logo  :  String,
    things : [String]
});
```

This is my add method in my angular.js controller:

```
    $scope.submit_thing  = function() {
        var data = $.param({ 'thing_name': $scope.newthing, 'thing_logo': $scope.newlogo, 'things': $scope.selected.things });
        $http.post("http://10.0.0.2:8080/thing/add",
            data,
            {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.data);
        });
        ...
```

... but when I call `$scope.submit_thing` my node.js app output this ...

```
{ thing_name: 'eeeee',
  thing_logo: 'eeeee',
  'things[]': [ 'Fishing', 'Mountain Biking' ] }
```

... and then I can find this record in my database, but the `things` array is empty.  Where in the heck does the `[]` come from? I think it is messing up my form data.  Shouldn't my form data be?

```
{ thing_name: 'eeeee',
  thing_logo: 'eeeee',
  'things': [ 'Fishing', 'Mountain Biking' ] }
```

**Update**:  I have change the line ...

```
        var data = $.param({ 'thing_name': $scope.newthing, 'thing_logo': $scope.newlogo, 'things': $scope.selected.things });
```

... to ...

```
        var data = { 'thing_name': $scope.newthing, 'thing_logo': $scope.newlogo, 'things': $scope.selected.things };
```

... but that has seemed to make things worse.  Now I get this output from my node.js console ...

```
{ '{"thing_name":"thing","thing_logo":"thing","things":["Running","Fishing"]}': '' }
```

** Update 2**:

Ok I am now doing this in my thingCtrl.js file:

```
    $scope.submit_thing  = function() {
        var data = $.param({ "thing_name": $scope.newthing, "thing_logo": $scope.newlogo, "things": JSON.stringify($scope.selected.things)});
```

... so know the a complete record is making it into my mongodb, but the mongo record looks like this:

```
> db.things.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5646bb2e4235cd620080a969"), "thing_name" : "test001", "thing_logo" : "testlogo", "things" : [ "[\"Skiing\",\"Mountain Biking\"]" ], "__v" : 0 }
>
```

Does it matter that the strings in the array `things` have the quote escape?
What's up with that?

Comment: Have you tried var data = { thing_name: $scope.newthing, thing_logo: $scope.newlogo, things: $scope.selected.things } ?

Comment: I think the proble is uu pass to the server object where thing is true. U should pass smth like this : {name: 'Name', logo: 'Logo', things: ['Fishing']}. Could u try do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's what I had to do ...

```
  $scope.submit_thing  = function() {
        var data = Object({ 'thing_name': $scope.newthing, 'thing_logo': $scope.newlogo, 'things': $scope.selected.things});
        $http.post("http://10.0.0.2:8080/vendor/add",
            JSON.stringify(data)
            //{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
         ).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.data);
        });
```

I think the thing that did was commenting out the headers line.